# Nested For and Try Loop - Main loop doesn't solve

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, try-except

My Data is a list of lists with r rows with varying length containing strings of data - some of which are floats but have been read in as strings.

I would like to loop first through all rows, then through all *elements* and then apply a try/except function on said *elements* to find the first instance of a string in the row that can be converted to a float.

My code outputs as expected for when I explicitly tell the second loop for which row it should do the operation, however, when I try to loop over all rows, it only outputs the expected output for the first row and none of the following rows.

The expected output list *float_index* (with lenght = len(data)) would be a list with the index of the first convertable element for all rows.

Here's the code with the explicit row definition outputting [2], since for the second row, it's the 2nd element that is convertible to a float:

```
data = [['Mittl.', 'Halleninnenpegel,', 'Volllast', 'Li', '124', '132', '132', '132', '139', '138', '141', '139', '131', '146'],
['Abgaskamin', 'LW', '130', '129', '121', '104', '100', '96', '94', '89', '86', '108']]


row= 1
floats = []
float_index = []
for i in data[row]:
    try:
        floats.append(str(int(float(i))))
        float_index = [data[row].index(floats[0])]
    except:
        pass
print(float_index)
```

Here's the code looping all rows in data, but only outputting the expected value for the first row float_index = [4], while the expected was float_index = [4,2]:

```
data = [['Mittl.', 'Halleninnenpegel,', 'Volllast', 'Li', '124', '132', '132', '132', '139', '138', '141', '139', '131', '146'],
['Abgaskamin', 'LW', '130', '129', '121', '104', '100', '96', '94', '89', '86', '108']]

floats = []
float_index = []
for r in range(len(data)):
    for i in data[r]:
        try:  
            floats.append(str(int(float(i))))
            float_index = [data[r].index(floats[0])]
        except:
            pass
print(float_index)
```

The *floats* list is probably the problem - it just collects all convertible elements into a long list with one row - I need the *floats* list to be of the same way as *data*, that it puts all convertible elements into new rows, so that by *floats[0]* I find the first elements for all rows, but somehow can't get my head around achieving this.

Would appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. "Does not work" is a totally useless description of a problem, and your code snippet is not a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so even if we tried we could not reproduce the issue ourselves. Please edit your post (do NOT post in comments) to add a true MCVE (cf link above) and proper description of the issue (if the result is incorrect, explain how and why, if you get an error post the exact error message and the full traceback).

Comment: @Skadam what is data defined as?

Comment: @RachelGallen I just updated the post - sorry, it's my first question asked on SO.

Comment: @RachelGallen I updated again, there's two rows of Data included now

Comment: @RachelGallen updated again, should be run-able now! :)

Comment: @Skadam, I don't know why you accepted an answer that was incorrect, but I have posted an answer for you below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to loop through each element just break out of the loop once the first one is found:

```
data = [['Mittl.', 'Halleninnenpegel,', 'Volllast', 'Li', '124', '132', '132', '132', '139', '138', '141', '139', '131', '146'],
['Abgaskamin', 'LW', '130', '129', '121', '104', '100', '96', '94', '89', '86', '108']]

floats = []
float_index = []
for lest in data:
    float_temp = None
    float_ind_temp = None
    for el in lest:
        try:
            float_temp = str(int(float(el)))
            floats.append(float_temp)
            float_index_temp = lest.index(float_temp)
            break
        except:
            pass
    float_index.append(float_index_temp)
print(float_index)
```

Comment: please do NOT post such a totally wrong exception handling example, this is one of the worst things you can do (cf https://realpython.com/the-most-diabolical-python-antipattern/)

Comment: Could you provide a solution then please?